# NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I was in the impression that V12 can now handle higher order PDES but for this particular case it fails to produce any solution.

```
pde1 = D[F[x, y], {x, 3}] + F[x, y]*D[F[x, y], {x, 2}] == 
   y*(D[F[x, y], {x, 1}]*D[D[F[x, y], {x, 1}], y] - 
      D[F[x, y], {x, 2}]*D[F[x, y], {y, 1}]);

pde2[Pr_, L1_] = 
  1/Pr*D[T[x, y], {x, 2}] + F[x, y]*D[T[x, y], {x, 1}] - 
    2*L1*D[F[x, y], {x, 1}]*T[x, y] == 
   y*(D[F[x, y], {x, 1}]*D[T[x, y], {y, 1}] - 
      D[T[x, y], {x, 1}]*D[F[x, y], {y, 1}]);

With[{lb = 5}, bcs = {{F[0, y] + y == -y*Derivative[0, 1][F][0, y], 
    Derivative[1, 0][F][0, y] == 0, T[0, y] == 1}, 
    {Derivative[1, 0][F][lb, y] == 1, T[lb, y] == 0}}];

Clear@solfunc
With[{lb = 5}, 
 solfunc[Pr_, L1_: 0.5] :=NDSolve[{pde1, pde2[Pr, L1], bcs}, {F, T}, {x, 0, lb}, {y, 0, 1}]]

(sollst[#] = solfunc[#]) & /@ {0.7, 3}
```

The above system has been solved using truncation method getting a series solution in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1115/1.3449827). The approach suggested by the authors is long and a tedious one. I was wondering whether it is possible to solve this system directly or there is some other efficient way to get the solution.

Any suggestion on how to solve such system?

Comment: How did you get this system?

Comment: The system has five boundary conditions in `x`, as expected.  But, what are the two boundary conditions in `y`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey The authors haven't mentioned anything about the bcs wrt `y` but I suspect we can use some trivial ones, such as `F[x,0]==0, T[x,0]==0`. I tried with it but no solution.

Comment: With those initial conditions, it becomes an initial-value problem.  Try specifying that `NDSolve` use the numerical method of lines.  If that does not work either, descritize the PDEs in `x` by hand to create a large system of ODEs in `y` which almost certainly can be solved numerically.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried with `MethodofLines` using these cs as ics but no luck.

Comment: Too bad.  It appears you need to discretize in `x` by hand and then solve the resulting system of ODEs.  Although tedious, it should work, I think.  (The cross-derivatives in the first PDE could be an issue.)

Comment: Have a look at the message ref page ref/message/NDSolve/femcmsd.

Comment: @zhk The article explores the well-known system of equations of the boundary layer. And you have something completely different. Where did you get this system of equations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have the same system as given in the paper. Please see eqns (8-11) in the paper.

Comment: @zhk (8-11) is a 1D system, and you have 2D. In the case of 1D, the system is simplified since it reduces to ODEs. In the case of 2D, the system is complicated. What do you see the point in this?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The system becomes of an ODE when we get rid of `y`, taking it zero or treat it as a parameter. My point is, instead of going for the over simplification why not solve it a PDE system by not treating `y` as a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a partial solution.  Begin by noting that

- `pde1` does not involve `T` and so can be solved for `F` and the solution then inserted into `pde2` to solve for `T`.
- The boundary condition `F[0, y] + y == -y*Derivative[0, 1][F][0, y]` should be integrated to yield `-y/2`.
- The boundary condition `Derivative[1, 0][F][lb, y] == 1` is inconsistent with the initial condition `F[x,0] == 0` at `x = lb, y = 0` but can be made consistent with the standard trick, `Derivative[1, 0][F][lb, y] == 1 - Exp[-10 y]`,
- The error message cited in the question is associated with FEM and can be avoided by using `Method -> "MethodOfLines"`.

With these changes, `pde1` can be solved as follows:

```
lb = 5;
pde1 = D[F[x, y], {x, 3}] + F[x, y]*D[F[x, y], {x, 2}] == 
    y*(D[F[x, y], {x, 1}]*D[D[F[x, y], {x, 1}], y] - D[F[x, y], {x, 2}]*D[F[x, y], {y, 1}]);
bcs = {F[0, y] == -y/2, Derivative[1, 0][F][0, y] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][F][lb, y] == 1 - Exp[-10 y], F[x, 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde1, bcs}, F[x, y], {x, 0, lb}, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "MethodOfLines"];
Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, lb}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, F}, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now it is working like a charm. Thx as always for your valuable answers.